# PHP $_SESSION[] variable apparent mismatch?

Tags: php

I assigned a value "ventas" to $_SESSION["area"] and when I echo it for testing I get the value. But when using it on a switch it doesnt bring the echo back. Am I doing something wrong? Missing something?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["area"];
switch($_SESSION["area"])
{
    case "ventas":
    echo "ventas";
    break;
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what does a `var_dump($_SESSION)` show? Make sure that the value really is `ventas` and not something like `ventas[space]`. If it's got hidden characters, the var-dump will show a string length BIGGER than `(6)`.

Comment: heres what it brings:array(12) { ["u"]=> string(3) "dan" ["c"]=> string(6) "manola" ["id"]=> string(7) "2
" ["usuario"]=> string(9) "dan
" ["clave"]=> string(12) "manola
" ["area"]=> string(6) "ventas" ["nivel"]=> string(7) "1
" ["nombre"]=> string(13) "daniela
" ["segundo"]=> string(6) "
" ["paterno"]=> string(15) "rodriguez
" ["materno"]=> string(12) "aranda
" ["email"]=> string(28) "danna.aranda@gmail.com
" }

Comment: Try putting in `default` case and see echo something in it. If it works then there is a hidden character in `$_SESSION['area']`

Comment: Where did you put that `var_dump()` @user1561911? Try putting it **right** above the `switch` statement, to make sure you're not altering anything on the way down.

Comment: I see you've accepted an answer. I'm very curious to know what the issue was. Can you discuss it?

Comment: He/she was wrongly assigning it @asprin, which doesn't quite make sense from that `var_dump()` he/she showed us, but hey....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make that session = a value, or it would just return NULL or won't find anything in the switch. It seems it isn't a correctly assigned value.

```
$_SESSION['area'] = "ventas";
```

Comment: Read the question again dude.

Comment: IF you have assigned it a valid value it should be fine, can we see the rest of the code?

Please don't negative this when I pointed out where your problem lies.

Comment: '*You need to make that session = a value, or it would just return NULL.*' The OP says he/she **has** already assigned the value to the variable. He/she may of assigned it wrong, but it's been assigned. So this answer provides no help at all.

Comment: If it's assigned wrong then it hasn't been assigned at all.. Switch is taking this variable as NULL because of how it was assigned!

Comment: Thanks! I did assign a value to it and it does bring the echo back when calling it but for use in a switch it won't accept it

Comment: No. If it's assigned 'wrong', then it's been assigned with an incorrect value. What makes you think the `switch` statement is seeing `NULL`? It's just not seeing `'ventas'`. Take a look at the OP's `var_dump()` comment to see that it has been assigned with the correct value.

Comment: Can you please put the code up where you assigned it? Thanks.

Comment: I agree however it still brings null after checking with a var_dump:   heres what it brings:array(12) { ["u"]=> string(3) "dan" ["c"]=> string(6) "manola" ["id"]=> string(7) "2 " ["usuario"]=> string(9) "dan " ["clave"]=> string(12) "manola " ["area"]=> string(6) "ventas" ["nivel"]=> string(7) "1 " ["nombre"]=> string(13) "daniela " ["segundo"]=> string(6) " " ["paterno"]=> string(15) "rodriguez " ["materno"]=> string(12) "aranda " ["email"]=> string(28) "danna.aranda@gmail.com " }

Comment: I'm guessing your assigning it by something along the lines of... $_SESSION['session'] = $array_name["area"]; Correct?

Comment: OK! So after checking the assigning of the variables (going back to the original file) noticed that it had a new line code (br /) afterwards (dont know why). So you were all right had to go back to reassign values.

I very much appreciate your help all of you!